# Not let the user unfocus the frame?

Tags: java, swing, focus, frame

So you know how In Microsoft Word, when you go to File --> Options and it won't let you do anything else until you close it? Is there anything like that in Java?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, they are called modal dialogs. [Modality tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html).

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know what it was called :)